# Copulas with positive likelihood ratio dependence

Tags: copula

Let $C(,)$ is an absolutely continuous two dimensional copula. Let the $C_{1}$, $C_{2}$, $C_{12}$ denote the derivatives wrt to the first, second, and mixed variables respectively. We say $C$ is PLR if and only if $C_{1}(x,y) C_{2}(x,y) \leq C(x,y) C_{12}(x,y)$ for all $x,y \in [0,1]$. Are there bounds on $C_{11}$ and $C_{22}$ ? ( I am looking for bounds that does depend on $C$. We know that $C_{11},C_{22} \leq 0$ and this bound is attained if $C$ is the independence copula).